# Reading 0 and 1 from a database and retrieving in a checkbox

Tags: php, database, checkbox, html-table, member

I am trying to create a members table, using a PHPmyadmin database, and in the database, there is a 0 & 1 field, and I want to transform the 0 and 1 in a checkbox, for each member. Is an editable table, so the table might be in a form. Here is what I did:

```
<?php
include('../../config.php'); 

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acars_users");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Dados Pessoais</th>
<th>Origem</th>
<th>Dados de Redes</th>
<th width='220px'>Base</th>
<th>Patente</th>
<th>Horas</th>
<th>&Eacute; Ativo?</th>
<th>Dinheiro</th>
<th>Senha</th>
<th>Op&ccedil;&otilde;es</th>
</tr>";



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 

  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td width='300px'>" . "<form action=editar.php method=POST><input name=username size=7 type=text value=".$row['username']." /></br><input name=nome size=10 type=text value=".$row['nome']." /><input name=sobrenome size=20 type=text value=".$row['sobrenome']." /></br><input name=email size=25 type=text value=".$row['email']." />" . "</td>";

  echo "<td>" . "<input name=datanascimento size=10 type=text value=".$row['datanascimento']." /></br><input name=pais size=10 type=text value=".$row['pais']." /></br><input name=cidade size=30 type=text value=".$row['cidade']." />" . "</td>";

  echo "<td>" . "IVAO:&nbsp;<input name=idivao size=8 type=text value=".$row['idivao']." /></br>VATSIM:&nbsp;<input name=idvatsim size=8 type=text value=".$row['idvatsim']." />" . "</td>";

  echo "<td>" . "<input name=base size=8 type=text value=".$row['base']." />" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=rank size=10 type=text value=".$row['rank']." /></br>Admin &nbsp;<input name=admin size=1 type=checkbox value=".$row['admin']." /></br>DOV &nbsp; <input name=dov size=1 type=checkbox value=".$row['dov']." /></br>Checador &nbsp; <input name=checador size=1 type=checkbox value=".$row['checador']." />" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=horas size=6 type=text value=".$row['horas']." />" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=checkbox name='isactive[]' value=".$row['isactive']." />" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=dinheiro size=10 type=text value=".$row['dinheiro']." />" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=password size=10 type=password value=".$row['password']." />" . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input name=edit_id value=".$row['id']." type=hidden><input type=submit value=Editar ></form><form action=deletarexist.php method=POST><input name=delete_id value=".$row['id']." type=hidden><input type=submit value=Demitir></form>" . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Line breaks are allowed in HTML. And if you don't `echo` it, you can even make it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$chkd=$row['isactive']?'checked="checked"':''; // 0: false; 1: true
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='isactive[]' value='{$row['isactive']}' $chkd></td>";
```

(Although, you should look into using a templatingg system (such as smarty) rather than echoing html fragments. It seems at bit weird in the start, but as soon as you get used to it, you'll never look back-)

Comment: yeah that's better than mine, I just did a fast example, it's late :)

Comment: @galaxyAbstractor I have to admit, I copied the code from your answer before modifiing it... Thanks (and sorry if I sounded a bit harsh)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the checkbox checked, and in that case you need to add the `checked="checked"` attribute to the checkbox.

So what you would do would be something like this:

```
if($row['isactive'] == 1){
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='isactive[]' value=".$row['isactive']. checked='checked' />" . "</td>";
} else {
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='isactive[]' value=".$row['isactive']." />" . "</td>";
}
```

For the value you probably should have something to identify the checkbox, like a memberid depending on what you are using it for.